# Refresh serial number after update Kendo Grid

Tags: .net, kendo-grid

I have kendo grid and insert serial number as following:

```
var rowNumber = 0;

    function resetRowNumber(e) {
        rowNumber = 0;
    }

    function renderNumber(data) {
        return ++rowNumber;
    }
```

It loads serial number order but when i edit-update record in any row of kendo grid then the serial number start from last serial number. I want to get serial number order in proper after grid updation. Can anyone help me to do this?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Can you post your grid code?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with databounding.. Now its working good. I have included my grid code here .

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<SSRWAWeb.Models.MYDataWrappers.ViewMYJobItem>()
        .Name("grid")
 .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Template(t => { }).Title("Line No").ClientTemplate("#= renderNumber(data) #");
            columns.Bound(c => c.line_num).Title("Line #");
            columns.Bound(c => c.part_num).Title("Part Number");

 })
         .Events(e => { e.Edit("assignNumber"); e.Save("orderUpdate"); e.Cancel("cancelChanges"); e.DataBound("resetRowNumber"); e.DataBinding("resetEditRowNumber"); })
```

Thank you..